# Best way to present a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

i'm working on multiple frameworks and my question is just a "philosophic" one.

I created an utility function to show view controllers

```
static func presentViewController(identifier: String, storyboardName: String = "Main", presentationStyle: UIModalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: InternalConstants.bundle)
    var viewResult: UIViewController
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        viewResult = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: identifier)
    } else {
        viewResult = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    viewResult.modalPresentationStyle = presentationStyle
    var top = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while top?.presentedViewController != nil {
       top = top!.presentedViewController
    }
    top!.present(viewResult, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

First of all, is this a correct way to present a view controller or is there a better way?

Then, is it better to present a view controller in a navigation controller or not?

Comment: I would change the last line to `top?.present(viewResult, animated: true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, is this a correct way to present a view controller or is there a better way?

as long as it's working then it's correct it's just your way of doing this specific thing, but is it the right thing to do as for an `iOS` and `UIKit` standpoint the answer is no it's usually is a bad thing to present a viewController by looking at the `rootViewController's` `presentedViewController` because it's not guaranteed that the last `presentedViewController` you find is a good thing to present on it and you won't know until it breaks, that `presentedViewController` could be a `UISearchController` and if you use `UIContentContainer` or `ContainerView` from storyboards, you might have a small viewController that is just a `UISlider` at the end, this could be bad for viewController appearance and disappearance

another problem that you will face is when you need to pass data to and from the viewController that you presenting by using this approach you don't even have a reference to the viewController you are presenting, because you are only passing an `identifier`

from an `MVC` standpoint you should never try to present viewController from a `UIView` by calling your function from your view directly *Thats Bad Practice*

if you take a look at the `UIKit` SDK if you ever try to present any system `UIViewController` you will find that you have the responsibility of instantiating and presenting the vc for example `UIImagePickerController`, `UIActivityViewController`, `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, `UIDocumentMenuViewController`, `UIPrinterPickerController`, `UIVideoEditorController`

Apple themselves didn't go for providing a function to present theirs system vcs

instead if you are developing a framework and don't want to give users access to your viewControllers you should make you own window and give it a `rootViewController`

Apple also has many examples for this too, in the `AuthenticationServices` framework for security reasons you should not have a reference to the safari web browser they have something called `ASWebAuthenticationSession` that controls the flow of presenting and dismissing the Safari Web ViewController by calling `start()` and `cancel()` functions

also the users of your framework will not always want to present your viewController with the default presentation animation they might want to use custom viewContollers animations which they will need access to the `transitioningDelegate` property on the viewController

imagine every public useful property on `UIViewController` will not be accessible if you go with this approach

> Then, is it better to present a view controller in a navigation controller or not?

as for this part it's totally fine to present anything on a navigationController

**Storyboards headaches**
as for the storyboards initialization headaches there are plenty of articles out there talking about optimizing the storyboards initialization call site for that I would recommend doing something like this

```swift
extension UIStoryboard {
    enum AppStoryBoards: String {
        case
        login,
        main,
        chat,
        cart
    }

    convenience init(_ storyboard: AppStoryBoards, bundle: Bundle? = nil) {
        self.init(name: storyboard.rawValue.prefix(1).capitalized + storyboard.rawValue.dropFirst(), bundle: bundle)
    }
}
```

This way you can initialize a storyboards using `enum` which improves the call site to be like this

```swift
let login = UIStoryboard.init(.login)
```

then you can have another extension for view controller initialization like this

```swift
extension UIStoryboard {
    func instantiateInitialVC<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
        return self.instantiateInitialViewController() as! T
    }

    func instantiateVC<T: UIViewController>(_: T.Type) -> T {
        return self.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: T.self)) as! T
    }
}
```

and you can then call it like this

```swift
let loginVC = UIStoryboard.init(.login).instantiateInitialVC()
```

or this

```swift
let loginVC = UIStoryboard.init(.login).instantiateVC(LoginViewController.self)
```

by doing that you improve your overall code for presenting any viewController

```swift
let dvc = UIStoryboard.init(.login).instantiateVC(LoginViewController.self)
dvc.plaplapla = "whatever"
present(dvc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

> First of all, is a correct way to present a view controller or there is a better way?

instead of a utility make it inside

```
 extension UIViewController {
   func ......
 }
```

> Then, is better to present a view controller in a navigation controller or not?

a nav is oriented for push/pop but it's also not wrong to use it to present another vc